# Decompiling a 1990 DOS application

Tags: debugging, decompiling, decompiler, disassembly

I have some crucial data written decades ago by an ancient 16bit DOS application.
There are no docs, no source, and no information about the author. Just the 16 bit exe.
I guess it's time for me to learn how to decompile stuff, since it seems the only way to restore file format.
I've tried OllyDbg, it looks really great, but it can't 16 bit.

So, is there a disassembler/debugger capable of working with such executables?
Thanks.

UPD: I know DOSbox, the app runs in it all right. The problem is, I don't need to run it, I need to understand the file format in which it writes data. Or maybe I don't know something about DOSbox and it can run as a debugger/decompiler as well? Or do you mean starting some old 16bit DOS debugger/decompiler in DOSbox? The latter sounds like an idea, but could you please name a decent DOS debugger, then?

Comment: Have you tried DOSBox? I would try emulating the correct environment, decompiling will be much harder.

Comment: If you tell us the name of the DOS program, there's a chance someone will recognise it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton This chance is close to zero since it was written by a PhD student for his thesis and was not distributed by any means. It's called 'OMWE.EXE", so yeah.

Comment: How is the data crucial? How do you get at the data? When was the last time you got at the data? Can the program read the file and reveal the data in a way that it can be captured so then you don't depend on the program? Why is this an issue all of a sudden, in the year 2013: why weren't you picking at this in 2003? If you can still run the program, like you could in 1993 or 2003, what is the problem? (Getting sudden cold feet about proprietary programs for legacy platforms?)

Comment: @Kaz 1) It will make a great difference for my own PhD thesis. 2) My scientific adviser gave me. 3) No. (I wouldn't be asking here otherwise). 4) Because I am writing my thesis NOW. (I was in school a decade ago). 5) Because I need the data, which the program only writes but doesn't read. 6) The author is dead for a decade and did not mention any licensing for his program when he was alive.

Comment: Perhaps you can find out what program was used to create OMWE.EXE by opening it in a text editor. There could be some text giving a hint, like "Turbo Pascal", which would guide you to a suitable disassembler.

Answer (score 5):

disassembling tool:

use IDA Freeware https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml
you won't find any better tool for reversing - even for old dos programs :)

most other tools are only capable of doing disassembling for 32bit and don't reach in any way the analyze features of IDA - its the gold standard tool of reverse engineering

debugger:
dosbox got its own builtin debugger (reachable through the "debug" command on command line)
but you need to build your own version of dosbox with activated debugger (oder better heavy-debug) see: http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=3944

or if you got a ida licence with the sdk there is an dosbox<->ida-debugger plugin available
currently linux only https://github.com/wjp/idados

file format:
do you know what the file contains (what do you want from the file)
very complex information or "just" some lists of values?

maybe its better to start here with an hex-editor (http://mh-nexus.de/de/hxd/) and known result-values to compare

what program uses the data currently (or only the program itself)? maybe its possible to understand how the data is read in this program?

program itself:
how large is the exe? 
console program or a big super gfx power app?
real 16bit or 32bit with dos-extender?
a single exe or overlays(dos-dlls)?

can you give access to the executable?

your turn

Comment: Necroposting mode on:
I'm trying to decompile a 16 bit app, and I fail to do it with IDA/Hex Rays. Using 6.8.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml). It's the de-facto disassembler for pretty much anything.

You can get more help on this at https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is a trial version that can't save and has limited format support.

Answer (score 1):

You do not necessarily need to disassemble a program in order to figure out the format in which it writes data.

Perhaps you can do differential analysis on it. Change some inputs to the program, have it write the data, and watch how the file changes.

I have some vintage hardware devices here which can dump their NVRAM settings over MIDI in a binary format (in one case, a single SysEx message with a binary blob in it). If I wanted to know what the format is, I'd make small, systematic changes to the settings, and perform dumps, then see what bits in the binary data are changing.

You really are probably best off attacking the data, rather than the program.

Comment: Thanks but the program was intended to save data from several sensors of a track testing railway car. (Which, even if it still exists, is in other country). So yeah, not much possibilities for attacking data in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Dosbox is probably a thing to try.

You might also look at http://hte.sourceforge.net/ .

Comment: I've added my comment about DOSbox to the question. HTE, on the other hand, looks promising, thanks for that.